# Error in pig 0.17.0 (ERROR 2998:Unhandled internal error) in Windows 10

Tags: apache-pig

[image]

i am running the following command in local mode:

```
      grunt> data1= LOAD 'e:/input/stud.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as(sid:int,sname:chararray);
```

```
2021-04-08 12:35:46,286 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
grunt> DUMP data1;
```

when dumping the data onto the screen it is showing error.

Comment: You should give us the error message you get in a text form, not an image.

Comment: Based on the error, I dont think you installed Hadoop and/or winutils correctly